# join quanteda dfm top ten 1grams with all dfm 2 thru 5grams

Tags: r, nlp, sparse-matrix, quanteda

To conserve memory space when dealing with a very large corpus sample i'm looking to take just the top 10 1grams and combine those with all of the 2 thru 5grams to form my single quanteda::dfmSparse object that will be used in natural language processing [nlp] predictions. Carrying around all the 1grams will be pointless because only the top ten [ or twenty ] will ever get used with the simple back off model i'm using.

I wasn't able to find a quanteda::dfm(corpusText, . . .) parameter that instructs it to only return the top ## features. So based on comments from package author @KenB in other threads i'm using the dfm_select/remove functions to extract the top ten 1grams and based on the "quanteda dfm join" search results hit "[concatenate dfm matrices in 'quanteda' package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363711/concatenate-dfm-matrices-in-quanteda-package)" i'm using rbind.dfmSparse??? function to join those results.

So far everything looks right from what i can tell. Thought i'd bounce this game plan off of SO community to see if i'm overlooking a more efficient route to arrive at this result or some flaw in solution I've arrived at thus far.

```
corpusObject <- quanteda::corpus(paste("some corpus text of no consequence that in practice is going to be very large\n",
    "and so one might expect a very large number of ngrams but for nlp purposes only care about top ten\n",
    "adding some corpus text word repeats to ensure 1gram top ten selection approaches are working\n"))
corpusObject$documents
dfm1gramsSorted <- dfm_sort(dfm(corpusObject, tolower = T, stem = F, ngrams = 1))
dfm2to5grams <- quanteda::dfm(corpusObject, tolower = T, stem = F, ngrams = 2:5)
dfm1gramsSorted; dfm2to5grams 
#featnames(dfm1gramsSorted); featnames(dfm2to5grams)
#colSums(dfm1gramsSorted); colSums(dfm2to5grams)

dfm1gramsSortedLen <- length(featnames(dfm1gramsSorted))
# option1 - select top 10 features from dfm1gramsSorted
dfmTopTen1grams <- dfm_select(dfm1gramsSorted, pattern = featnames(dfm1gramsSorted)[1:10]) 
dfmTopTen1grams; featnames(dfmTopTen1grams)
# option2 - drop all but top 10 features from dfm1gramsSorted
dfmTopTen1grams <- dfm_remove(dfm1gramsSorted, pattern = featnames(dfm1gramsSorted)[11:dfm1gramsSortedLen]) 
dfmTopTen1grams; featnames(dfmTopTen1grams)

dfmTopTen1gramsAndAll2to5grams <- rbind(dfmTopTen1grams, dfm2to5grams)
dfmTopTen1gramsAndAll2to5grams;
#featnames(dfmTopTen1gramsAndAll2to5grams); colSums(dfmTopTen1gramsAndAll2to5grams)
data.table(ngram = featnames(dfmTopTen1gramsAndAll2to5grams)[1:50], frequency = colSums(dfmTopTen1gramsAndAll2to5grams)[1:50],
keep.rownames = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

/eoq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For extracting the top 10 unigrams, this strategy will work just fine:

1. sort the dfm by the (default) decreasing order of overall feature frequency, which you have already done, but then add a step tp slice out the first 10 columns.
2. combine this with the 2- to 5-gram dfm using `cbind()` (not `rbind()`)).

That should do it:

```
dfmCombined <- cbind(dfm1gramsSorted[, 1:10], dfm2to5grams)
head(dfmCombined, nfeat = 15)
# Document-feature matrix of: 1 document, 195 features (0% sparse).
# (showing first document and first 15 features)
#        features
# docs    some corpus text of to very large top ten no some_corpus corpus_text text_of of_no no_consequence
#   text1    2      2    2  2  2    2     2   2   2  1           2           2       1     1              1
```

Your example code includes some use of data.table, although this does not appear in the question.  In v0.99 we have added a new function `textstat_frequency()` which produces a "long"/"tidy" format of frequencies in a data.frame that might be helpful:

```
head(textstat_frequency(dfmCombined), 10)
#        feature frequency rank docfreq
# 1         some         2    1       1
# 2       corpus         2    2       1
# 3         text         2    3       1
# 4           of         2    4       1
# 5           to         2    5       1
# 6         very         2    6       1
# 7        large         2    7       1
# 8          top         2    8       1
# 9          ten         2    9       1
# 10 some_corpus         2   10       1
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Is the textstat_frequency()$rank column doing something interesting to break ties in the case of ngrams with the same feature length, i.e. 1/2/3/n-grams size, and same frequency?

Comment: I think it's random - it uses `data.table::setorder()`.